# MultiColor Label Control

Tags: c#, winforms, label, richtextbox, rtf

Is it at all possible to make a `Label` multi-colored? I have a `RichTextBox` that the user can type text into and format as required; I need to be able to display the resulting text, with the correct styles set by the user inside a `Label` control.

Anyone have any suggestions/advice/links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be easier to just use RichTextBoxes for your labels.  Make them readonly and borderless.

<s>[This link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/TransparentTextBox.aspx) may help you to make the background transparent.</s> (Link is broken)

Comment: thanks for the tip. is there w\an easy way that you know of to make the standard rtf's backcolor transparent?

Comment: Just make it the same as its parent form/panel... smoke and mirrors!

Comment: is it possible to check to see what control is "under" the rtf? because my users will be dragging the rtf around the page, so no matter what's benieth it - it needs to be transparent all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/rtflabelcp.aspx?msg=2062925 ?

Comment: thank you for that link - i'm downloading it now [just finished downloading] and am going to check it out now.